# wpf data template binding (Dynamically generating form)

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to dynamically generate a form in `WPF`. I would like to do it using **XAML** not from the code behind(Which I am currently doing.).

If I have a **data template** like below, What is the parent controller that I can use for this.(Like we use `Listbox`)

I have dataTemplate like below

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FieldTemlate">
       <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
       <TextBox  VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What is your sorrounding XAML ? Do you want this control to repeat based on some bindings?

Comment: Yes. I have a `List` of my custom objects which has information about the field need to be in the form. I want to bind that `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) is what you need.

Here you can find an [example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/).